# Specific Length Regular Expression With Padding

Tags: javascript, regex

**Goal:** to make a generalized Regular Expression for a fixed length string inside a larger string. This string has a specified padding character, followed by an integer counter that increments. Ideally, there would be some way to say, "I want this group to be of length 10 and contain only one type of character followed by a different character."

I am trying to match this within variable data (could be numbers could be letters could be symbols):
The padding-characters + numbers add up to a specified length, here would be 5.

These are the allowed padding + number combinations.

```
$$$$1
$$$12
$$123
$1234
```

Here is an example:

```
<variable-data> <padding-characters> <numbers> <variable-data>
............... .................... ddddddddd ............... 
(where periods are any characters and 'd' is any digit)

Example Data:
ABC              $$$$                 1         $!@

Example Regex: 
ABC\$*\d+\$!@

Match: 
ABC$$$$1$!@
ABC$$$12$!@
ABC$$123$!@
ABC$1234$!@
ABC12345$!@

No Match:
ABC$$123456789$!@
ABC1$2$34$!@
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8SFi2A/1%22regex101)

**What I've Tried:**

```
ABC(?=.{5})\$*\d+\$!@
```

This does not work because it still matches into the next digits because of `\d+`.  Another thing I tried was

```
ABC(?=[\$\d]{5}[^\$\d])(\$*\d+)\$!@
```

Which aims to stop looking after it encounters a non-digit or non $, but that's not helpful since the next part of the string COULD start with a $ or a digit.

**The easiest Regex to solve this:**

```
(\$\$\$\$\d|\$\$\$\d\d|\$\$\d\d\d|\$\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d\d)
```

But I am trying to make this more generalized, and there can be a variable amount of padding E.G.

```
$$$$$$$$$1
$$$$$$$$12
...
```

Comment: Do you mean finishing *variable-data* wouldn't begin with digits at all?

Comment: @revo I am not sure what any of the <variable-data> will be before runtime.  They are all user defined.  They could be digits for sure.

Comment: So possibility for such an input string *ABC$$$$11!@* exists and it should be matched?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.  I tried to convey that with the periods and 'd' under the brackets themselves.

Comment: So why did you say *No match* for `ABC$$123456789$!@`. As per your requirements it should match.

Comment: @revo I've added an example of what I am trying to do.  You make a valid point that `ABC$$123456789$!@` is indeed acceptable for what I am saying, but I know what tokens are coming before and after, so I also check for those.  The greedy `\d+` is messing me up I think.

Comment: I do not quite understand the question either, but have a look at [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/YjJSGD/2/). The point with the fixed patterns is that you still need to somehow "anchor" this fixed parts (in .NET, an infinite width lookbehind comes handy, but this is JS).

Comment: I still don't get why `ABC$$123456789$!@` should not match, since even the tokens before and after are exactly the same as in the examples of matches. This seems to suggest you also know beforehand what `#padding + #digits`  must be (some constant). Otherwise I see no explanation why that longer string should not match.

Comment: I don't think it should match `ABC$$$$$$1$!@` @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I've been looking at this for too long.  I know everything about the "tokens" I am trying to make this regular expression for, see the example link I made. I also know the adjacent tokens are.  So I probably do what Wiktor suggested.  I might just be thinking about this wrong.

Comment: @revo: Right, perhaps. Then, [`ABC(?=\${0,4}\d)(?=[$\d]{5}\$)(\$*\d+)\$!@`](https://regex101.com/r/YjJSGD/3) might be an enhancement.

Comment: What about [`ABC(?!.{0,3}\d\$)([\$\d]{5})\$!@`](https://regex101.com/r/cG4ab5/1)?

Comment: Try to expand the solution. It needs to work with *variable-data*.

Comment: @trincot that's pretty smart.  I think that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: OK, I have posted it as an answer then ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look ahead to check that you don't have an inverted sequence of padding character and digit within the scope of the next 5 characters, and then require and capture 5 characters that are only digits and padding characters:

[`ABC(?!.{0,3}\d\$)([\$\d]{5})\$!@`](https://regex101.com/r/cG4ab5/1)

If you need at least one digit, then:

[`ABC(?!.{0,3}\d\$)([\$\d]{4}\d)\$!@`](https://regex101.com/r/cG4ab5/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
ABC(?=.{5}\$!@)\$*\d+\$!@
```

This is very similar to your first attempt, but with the slight difference that the lookahead also contains the terminating string. This gives it something to anchor to, to make sure the regex doesn't match anything more.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted something that didn't depend on the next token, though. This does seem to answer my original question.